# Common phpmyadmin for apache2 and nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, apache2, nginx-config

I am trying to use common phpmyadmin in nginx installed using apache2 in my local machine.

I have tried many blogs and videos but phpmyadmin is not working in my local.

For example I have tried following [url](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/install-phpmyadmin-nginx-ubuntu-22-04), but it doesn't seem to work in my machine

I have my nginx doomain setup inside `/var/www/my_domain/`

Comment: And why do you need PHPMyAdmin? What's wrong with MySQL GUI clients?

Comment: @DanilaVershinin thanks for replying. I find it easy, may be becoz I have worked on phpmyadmin till now. What is your suggestion for the best GUI mysql clients ?. I already have mysql workbench but I feel it to be too much of functionality.